# Can't get multiple concurrent API calls to update response object consistently

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working with some API's that do not return the level of detail I need so I need to make additional API calls after the first call to get the needed details.  I am trying to improve performance by multi-threading the additional calls.  Here is the simplified version of the code I have currently:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderPayment
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public bool PaymentIsComplete { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderItem
    {
        public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderItemWithDetails : OrderItem
    {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public OrderPayment Payment { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<List<OrderItemWithDetails>> GetOrderItemsWithDetailsAsync()
    {
        var url = "orderItemsUrl";
        var tuple = await GetAsync<List<OrderItemWithDetails>>(url, null, null, null);
        List<OrderItemWithDetails> response = tuple.Item1;

        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        IEnumerable<int> customerIds = response.Select<OrderItemWithDetails, int>(o => o.CustomerId).Distinct();
        foreach (var customerId in customerIds)
        {
            int id = customerId;
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                url = "customerUrl?CustomerId=" + id;
                var customerTuple = await GetAsync<Customer>(url, null, null, null);
                response.Where(i => i.CustomerId == id).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Customer = customerTuple.Item1);
            }));
        }

        IEnumerable<int> orderIds = response.Select<OrderItemWithDetails, int>(o => o.OrderId).Distinct();
        foreach (var orderId in orderIds)
        {
            int id = orderId;
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                url = "orderUrl?OrderId=" + id;
                var orderTuple = await GetAsync<Order>(url, null, null, null);
                response.Where(i => i.OrderId == id).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Order = orderTuple.Item1);
            }));

            taskList.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                url = "paymentUrl?OrderId=" + id;
                var paymentTuple = await GetAsync<OrderPayment>(url, null, null, null);
                response.Where(i => i.OrderId == id).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Payment = paymentTuple.Item1);
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

        return response;
    }
```

The GetAsync is basically a wrapper around HttpClient.GetAsync with some additional logic including handling parsing the Json into an object.  I know the code in that call is good, it has been in use for a bunch of other calls for 2+ years.  The 2 issues I keep running into is that it is not waiting for the tasks to complete so the additional objects in OrderItemWithDetails are not consistently filled in and occasionally the Task.WhenAll throws an exception on the IEnumerable that source cannot be null.  I have tried just about every combination of the following changes, some work more consistently than others but none of them work 100% of the time:

- Change Task.Run to Task.Factory.StartNew
- Change the anonymous methods to not be async and change the await GetAsync to GetAsync.Result
- Change Task.WhenAll to Task.WaitAll
- Use ContinueWith and another anonymous method on the GetAsync calls to handle updating the response object
- Build the url before creating the task, change the anonymous methods to point directly to GetAsync and add the results to the response after all the tasks have run
- Creating a separate List of "statuses", before each task adding an entry to that list with a status of "NotDone", adding a line to the end of each task to update the status for that task to "Done", and replacing the Taks.WhenAll with a Where loop that waits for all entries in the list to be "Done"

Even the last option which I know is the completely wrong way of fixing this didn't work (still ended up with a bunch of null properties in the response) which totally baffles me.  I have been working on this for a couple of days now, have Googled like crazy and still have nothing close to working code.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After walking away from this for a couple days I came back and figured out what the issue was.  While the problem appeared to be that it wasn't waiting for the all tasks to complete because some of the sub-objects were not getting set that was not the issue.  As I have discovered in my limited work with multi-threading debugging can be very difficult because the code is non-linear.  The issue is that I am re-using the url variable so by the time the API was called the url had been updated in one of the other tasks.  So the http call was "successful" and returned an object but not the object expected so the Json parser generated an empty object so my response object got set to an empty object.  The null reference error actually wouldn't occur in the code above, the original version before I simplified it had to do an enumeration on one of the responses which failed when it was empty.